# BIM360 desgins using Model Derivate api is ABLE to see the SVF2

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to view SVF2 the BIM 360 Desgine using Model Derivate APIs ,but getting error like

NO ACCESS
Sorry,you don't have  the Required privileges to access this item

Please Contact  the Author

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usmLw.png)

Comment: are you able to view the same file in SVF format?

Comment: @Varunpatil YES able to see

Comment: Could you share more problem details? Although BIM360 doesn't support SVF2 currently, you can still load your model of the BIM360 design collaboration with OTG format. OTG is the internal code name of SVF2, see blog [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/svf2-public-beta-new-optimized-viewer-format) for the relationship between OTG and SVF2. And try this simple: https://github.com/yiskang/forge-viewhubmodels-nodejs-svf2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**click here Form Image***emphasized text*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69FPf.png)

I think SVF2 is not supporting FOR BIM360 Model till now,may be

Comment: SVF2  won't support BIM360 models, because in BIM360 files are auto-translated to SVF on uploading.